# Trying to call a method from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, the first of which has a datagrid view on it and the second is a data entry form.
I have created a method that refreshes the datagrid view on the first form but I want to call it when i close form number two. I quickly found that i cant call the method on the first form from the second form so I googled and found that when i open the second form i need to initialise it by using form1(this); however when i do this i get an error message:

'Form1' does not contain a contructor that takes 1 arguments

Does anyone know why this isnt working as i copied this from someone elses solution? Also what do i then need to put in my second form to be able to call the method in the first form?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Open New Record Form
                      
            Form1 form1 = new Form1(this);
            form1.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'Form1' does not contain a contructor that takes 1 arguments

Then give it a constructor which takes that argument.  For example:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _form2;

    public Form1(Form2 form2)
    {
        _form2 = form2;
    }

    // the rest of the class
}
```

The idea here is that if any given instance of `Form1` needs an instance of `Form2` to do its work, then it should require that instance on its constructor.  (You could even add some error checking in the constructor to make sure the passed instance isn't `null` for example.)  Then any time something creates an instance of `Form1`, it will need to supply that dependency.

Then any operation within `Form1` will have access to that dependency in the `_form2` field.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a method that refreshes the datagrid view on the first
> form but I want to call it when i close form number two.

What you can do is make Form1 update ITSELF when Form2 closes. You'd wire up the `FormClosed` event of Form2 when you create and display it:

```
// ... this is in FORM1 !!! ...
private void btnShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                 
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.FormClosed += (s2, e2) => this.Update(); // <-- change to your "update" method name
    f2.Show();
}
```